# Rounding a MYSQL datetime to earliest 15 minute interval in milliseconds (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, time, floor

I'm fetching a datetime from MYSQL which looks like:

2010-08-11 11:18:28

I need to convert it into the "floor" or the earliest 15 minute interval and output in milliseconds for another function.

So, this case would be:

2010-08-11 11:15:00 in milliseconds

---

Whoops! Sorry - need to clarify - I need code that will transform it into milliseconds WITHIN php!

---

**Doing a timing test revealed the following:**

```
$time_start = microtime(true);
for($i=0;$i<10000;$i++)
    floor(strtotime('2010-08-11 23:59:59')/(60*15))*60*15*1000;
$time_end = microtime(true);
echo 'time taken = '.($time_end - $time_start);
```

**time taken = 21.440743207932**

```
$time_start = microtime(true);
for($i=0;$i<10000;$i++)
    strtotime('2010-08-11 23:59:59')-(strtotime('2010-08-11 23:59:59') % 900);
$time_end = microtime(true);
echo 'time taken = '.($time_end - $time_start);
```

**time taken = 39.597450017929**

```
$time_start = microtime(true);
for($i=0;$i<10000;$i++)
    bcmul((strtotime('2010-08-11 23:59:59')-(strtotime('2010-08-11 23:59:59') % 900)), 1000);
$time_end = microtime(true);
echo 'time taken = '.($time_end - $time_start);
```

**time taken = 42.297260046005**

```
$time_start = microtime(true);
for($i=0;$i<10000;$i++)
    floor(strtotime('2010-08-11 23:59:59')/(900))*900000;
$time_end = microtime(true);
echo 'time taken = '.($time_end - $time_start);
```

**time taken = 20.687357902527**

**time taken = 19.32729101181**

**time taken = 19.938629150391**

It appears that the strtotime() function is a slow one and we probably should avoid using it doubly for every time its required. The timetaken(60*15) != timetaken(900) was a little bit of a surprise...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this work? Isn't there some function that would do this better?

```
echo floor(strtotime('2010-08-11 11:18:28')/(60*15))*60*15*1000;
1281505500000
Wednesday, August 11, 2010 11:15:00 AM

echo floor(strtotime('2010-08-11 11:28:28')/(60*15))*60*15*1000;
1281505500000
Wednesday, August 11, 2010 11:15:00 AM

echo floor(strtotime('2010-08-11 00:00:00')/(60*15))*60*15*1000;
1281465000000
Wednesday, August 11, 2010 12:00:00 AM

echo floor(strtotime('2010-08-11 23:59:59')/(60*15))*60*15*1000;
1281550500000
Wednesday, August 11, 2010 11:45:00 PM
```

Answer (score 1):

The following will give you the earliest 15 minute interval :

```
select UNIX_TIMESTAMP(YOURDATETIME)-MOD(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(YOURDATETIME), 900) 
from YOURTABLE
```

The result is in epoch seconds (seconds since '1970-01-01 00:00:00' UTC), if you want that value in milliseconds you should multiply by 1000 (either in the query or in PHP, as you see fit).

**EDIT**

In PHP for your set of values that would be :

```
$values = array('2010-08-11 11:18:28', '2010-08-11 11:28:28', '2010-08-11 00:00:00', '2010-08-11 23:59:59');
foreach($values as $value) {
    $result = (strtotime($value)-(strtotime($value) % 900));
    echo "$value -> $result\n";
}
```

When you multiply $result by 1000 (to get the value in ms) you will probably get an overflow and the result will be converted to a float. This is probably not what you want, so you might be better of using [bcmul](http://be.php.net/manual/en/function.bcmul.php) :

```
$result = bcmul((strtotime($value)-(strtotime($value) % 900)), 1000);
```

Comment: Hi! That looks rad for mysql, is there a smart way like this to do the same in php?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try and see what happens:

```
select DATE(myColumn) 
       + CONVERT(HOUR(myColumn),CHAR(2)) + ':'
       + CASE 
         WHEN MINUTE(myColumn) < 15 THEN '00'
         WHEN MINUTE(myColumn) < 30 THEN '15'
         WHEN MINUTE(myColumn) < 45 THEN '30'
         ELSE '45'
       END 
       + ':00' as myDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's see the worst solution:

```
<?php

$ts    = explode(' ', '2010-08-11 11:18:28');
$date  = explode('-', $ts[0]);
$time  = explode(':', $ts[1]);
$ts    = mktime($time[0], $time[1], $time[2], $date[1], $date[2], $date[0]);
$floor = mktime($time[0], round($time[1]/15)*15, 0, $date[1], $date[2], $date[0]);
```