# MYSQL Round the datetime to 15 minute

Tags: mysql, datetime, timestamp

I want to update the datetime round to 15 minutes in a MYSQL database table.

For Example:

If the dateTime is `2013-10-08 10:36:00`, I want to convert it into `2013-10-08 10:30:00`
Similarly,`2013-10-08 10:22:00` to `2013-10-08 10:15:00`

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12835768/rounding-time-to-the-nearest-15-minutes-in-php-mysql) answer but it converts datetime into seconds and return time only, I want date as well.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [MYSQL Date Time Round To Nearest Hour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9680144/mysql-date-time-round-to-nearest-hour)

Comment: Also see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480637/round-minute-down-to-nearest-quarter-hour

Comment: @TomaszKowalczyk: The first question is about rounding to whole hours which has rather simple solutions. The latter one is PHP.

Comment: You haven't done research in the subject you're asking. Answer marked as duplicate is easily adaptable, answer in PHP as well. Even the question mentioned inside your question is easily solved (hint: use `DATE_FORMAT()`, Luke)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer you have seen is quite useful, try this

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(datetime_field, ' ', -1) AS old_time,SEC_TO_TIME((TIME_TO_SEC(datetime_field) DIV 900) * 900) AS rounded_time, datetime_field FROM yourtable
```

You can get time from the `datetime_field` as substring and replace it with the rounded time.

If you want to update the datetime you can reply it and update it with `update` function:

```
UPDATE yourtable SET `datetime_field` =  REPLACE(datetime_filed,SUBSTRING_INDEX(datetime_field, ' ', -1),SEC_TO_TIME((TIME_TO_SEC(datetime_field) DIV 900) * 900))
```

Answer (score 26):

```
SELECT NOW() x,FROM_UNIXTIME(FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())/900)*900) y;
+---------------------+---------------------+
| x                   | y                   |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| 2013-10-10 09:50:20 | 2013-10-10 09:45:00 |
+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: thanks, I tried the other answer and it worked for me.. thanks anyway

Answer (score 5):

using unix_timestamp allows quite simpe arithmetic, change 15 in the code below to some other number if needed (such as 30)

```
select from_unixtime(round(unix_timestamp('2013-10-08 10:36:00')/(60*15))*(60*15)); 

= October, 08 2013 10:30:00+0000

select from_unixtime(round(unix_timestamp('2013-10-08 10:22:00')/(60*15))*(60*15)); 

= October, 08 2013 10:15:00+0000
```

see: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?20,131939,201089#msg-201089

Answer (score 2):

Use the same method as in the question you linked, but use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` functions instead. This will round either down or up to the nearest 15 minutes, remove the `+ 450` part if you want to round only down.

```
mysql> select FROM_UNIXTIME(((UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2013-08-07 12:05') + 450) DIV 900) * 900) AS roundtime;
+---------------------+
| roundtime           |
+---------------------+
| 2013-08-07 12:00:00 |
+---------------------+
```

Comment: thanks, I tried the other answer and it worked for me.. thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

You can modify answer you found (if you satisfied with it) just by concatenating date to the time:

```
SELECT CONCAT(DATE(time_field), 
              ' ',
              SEC_TO_TIME((TIME_TO_SEC(time_field) DIV 900) * 900))
FROM `your_table`
```

Comment: thanks, I tried the other answer and it worked for me.. thanks anyway