# Rounding a DATETIME value in MySQL to nearest minute

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a DATETIME column in a table `t` with values like:

```
|toStampActual      |
|-------------------|
|2014-09-09 13:00:00|
|2014-09-09 13:15:03|
|2014-09-09 13:14:55|
```

I need to be able to update those value to:

```
|toStampActual      |
|-------------------|
|2014-09-09 13:00:00|
|2014-09-09 13:15:00|
|2014-09-09 13:15:00|
```

Basically round to nearest minute...anything greater than :30 seconds goes up, anything less goes down.

I've found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/19291128/99401 and changed the SQL to

```
SELECT TIME_FORMAT(
    SEC_TO_TIME(
        (TIME_TO_SEC(toStampActual) DIV 60) * 60
    ), '%H:%i:%s') AS rounded_time 
FROM `t`
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9af73/2/0)

But this only rounds down.  How can I round up or down based on the seconds?

Comment: Try: `SELECT TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(((TIME_TO_SEC(toStampActual) +30) DIV 60) * 60), '%H:%i:%s') AS rounded_time FROM 't'`, see [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e112a/1/0).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One solution ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/24ef6c/3)) could be:

```
SEC_TO_TIME(((TIME_TO_SEC(toStampActual)+30) DIV 60) * 60)
```

Which just adds half of the `60` (value of `30`) before doing the `DIV`.

Or, just use `ROUND` ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/24ef6c/2))

```
SEC_TO_TIME((ROUND(TIME_TO_SEC(toStampActual)/60)) * 60)
```

Comment: does this work with datetime? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_sec-to-time "Returns the seconds argument, converted to hours, minutes, and seconds, as a TIME value. The range of the result is constrained to that of the TIME data type." I used FROM_UNIXTIME and UNIX_TIMESTAMP instead because of this.

Comment: The parenthesis aren't correct in either example.  There's four left parens but only three right parens. Add one more right paren on the right side.

Answer (score 0):

**Example of rounded to 5 minutes**

If yours `filed` is only `TIME` for example 01:41:00
the filed that contain the time called `fit.avergeTime`

First step:
We need to know the last character that contain the minutes, but only the `single minutes`,
for example, if the time is 01:41:00, we want to get only the minute 1 and not 41
we get that result by

```
SUBSTRING(fit.avergeTime, 5, 1)
```

then we use the case / when and add the correct numbers of minutes

```
case SUBSTRING(fit.avergeTime, 5, 1) 
    when 0 then fit.avergeTime 
    when 1 then DATE_ADD(fit.avergeTime, INTERVAL 4 MINUTE) 
    when 2 then DATE_ADD(fit.avergeTime, INTERVAL 3 MINUTE) 
    when 3 then DATE_ADD(fit.avergeTime, INTERVAL 2 MINUTE) 
    when 4 then DATE_ADD(fit.avergeTime, INTERVAL 1 MINUTE) 
    when 5 then fit.avergeTime 
    when 6 then DATE_ADD(fit.avergeTime, INTERVAL 4 MINUTE) 
    when 7 then DATE_ADD(fit.avergeTime, INTERVAL 3 MINUTE) 
    when 8 then DATE_ADD(fit.avergeTime, INTERVAL 2 MINUTE) 
    when 9 then DATE_ADD(fit.avergeTime, INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)
```

Hope this helps?

Answer (score -5):

```
update yourtable set new_start_time = CASE substring(new_start_time,5,1)+0
WHEN 0 THEN  addtime(new_start_time,'00:00') 
WHEN 1 THEN addtime(new_start_time,'-00:01') 
WHEN 2 THEN addtime(new_start_time,'-00:02') 
WHEN 3 THEN  addtime(new_start_time,'00:02') 
WHEN 4 THEN  addtime(new_start_time,'00:01') 
WHEN 5 THEN  addtime(new_start_time,'00:00') 
WHEN 6 THEN  addtime(new_start_time,'-00:01') 
WHEN 7 THEN  addtime(new_start_time,'-00:02') 
WHEN 8 THEN  addtime(new_start_time,'00:02') 
WHEN 9 THEN  addtime(new_start_time,'00:01') END
```