# Remove seconds on MySQL

Tags: mysql, seconds

I am new on MySQL and I don't know how to solve this

I have a table that contains datetime type. The coloumn's format is `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`, like this `2015-12-02 20:21:54`. I want to remove the second.

If the `second <= 30` then remove the second

```
2015-12-02 20:00:15 ---> 2015-12-02 20:00
```

If the `second > 30` then minute + 1

```
2015-12-02 20:21:54 ---> 2015-12-02 20:22
```

Does anyone know how to make query like this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rounding a DATETIME value in MySQL to nearest minute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25747539/rounding-a-datetime-value-in-mysql-to-nearest-minute)

Answer (score 0):

use `DATE_FORMAT`

```
SELECT 
if(DATE_FORMAT('2015-12-02 20:00:55','%s') <= 30,
DATE_FORMAT('2015-12-02 20:00','%Y-%m-%d %H:%i'),
DATE_FORMAT('2015-12-02 20:00','%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/35749)

Answer (score 0):

Does something like this work?

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(
        DATE_ADD(
            DATE_FORMAT(your_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:00'),
            INTERVAL IF (SECOND(your_date) < 30, 0, 1) MINUTE
        ),
        '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i'
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably do something like this (untested):

SELECT CASE SECOND(@yourDate) > 30 
    THEN DATE_ADD(@yourDate INTERVAL SECOND(@yourDate) SECOND)
    ELSE @yourDate;

You may wish to read the [date and time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html) part of the mysql manual.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE table_name SET 
     date_column=(CASE WHEN SECOND(date_column)>=30 THEN DATE_FORMAT(date_column,     '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:00')+INTERVAL 1 MINUTE 
        ELSE DATE_FORMAT(date_column, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:00') 
    END);