# Modify TIMESTAMP MySQL for use as Primary Key

Tags: mysql, timestamp, mariadb, heidisql

I have several tables in a MySQL database where I have defined my TIME_GMT (TIMESTAMP) as the primary key.  Problem is my TIME_GMT is never exactly the same between the tables.

For example, my first table (first row) has a primary key of 2014-12-30 05:00:05.  My next table (first row) has an primary key of 2014-12-14 05:00:07, and so on.

How would I go about modifying these primary keys to 2014-12-30 05:00:00 (round down to the lowest 10 seconds).

Comment: If you round them, you are much more likely to end up with duplicates. Is that a problem, since this is a primary key?

Comment: Not likely.  My data points occur every 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit more searching, I found this question that was previously asked and answered.

- [rounding time to the nearest 15 minutes in php/mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12835768/rounding-time-to-the-nearest-15-minutes-in-php-mysql)

I was able take the solution and modify my code.

```
SELECT
    SEC_TO_TIME((TIME_TO_SEC(TIME_GMT) DIV 10) * 10) AS TIME_GMT_MODIFY 
FROM table;
```