# split time interval in 15 min slot using mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime, group-by

I have 2 dates

start datetime = `2013-08-28 17:43:41` AND end datetime = `2013-08-28 22:23:51`

Now i want to convert start time to upper level 15 min interval like `2013-08-28 17:45:00` in this case, same way for end time converted in lower level 15 min interval like `2013-08-28 22:15:00`

Then after I want array of 15 min interval of difference between that time.

eg. for our case it should be

```
a[0] = 2013-08-28 17:45:00
a[0] = 2013-08-28 18:00:00
a[1] = 2013-08-28 18:15:00
a[2] = 2013-08-28 18:30:00
a[3] = 2013-08-28 18:45:00
a[4] = 2013-08-28 19:00:00
......like wise
```

I want this using mySql/php, but mysql is priority because data came from my database.

Comment: If you found duplicate then give me detail of original question. Thanks!

Comment: this is a link to convert all convert datetime to upper or lower 15 mins interval http://stackoverflow.com/a/3473286/2605821

Comment: Thanks! first problem resolved. Now I want to split it in interval and store in array.

Comment: split the value from database? didnt get explain..

Comment: In first step I want to convert start and end time to upper/lower level quarter hour. Now, I want to make array which store 15 min interval values between that start and end time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had solved this by PHP and query to retrieve start and end datetime from database.

```
$start_datetime = strtotime($start_datetime); //from 2013-08-28 17:43:41 to timestamp
$end_datetime = strtotime("+$duration minutes", $start_datetime); //from 2013-08-28 17:43:41 to timestamp

//loop till start time is less than end time
while ($start_datetime < $end_datetime)
{
     //add date as a key in first level array
     if(!array_key_exists(date('Y-m-d', $start_datetime), $booking_slot)) {
          $booking_slot[date('Y-m-d', $start_datetime)]=array();
     }

     //add time slot for perticular date's array
     array_push($booking_slot[date('Y-m-d', $start_datetime)], date("h:i A", $start_datetime));

     //add $interval to find next interval
     $start_datetime = strtotime("+$interval minutes", $start_datetime); //slot or interval
}
```

Answer (score 9):

If you have the start time and end time, convert them to UNIX timestamp. After that, simply create a loop that adds 15 minutes to the start time and keep going until you reach the end time.

Something like this:

```
$array_of_time = array ();
$start_time    = strtotime ("2013-08-28 17:45:00");
$end_time      = strtotime ("2013-08-28 22:15:00");

$fifteen_mins  = 15 * 60;

while ($start_time <= $end_time)
{
   $array_of_time[] = date ("Y-m-d H:i:s", $start_time);
   $start_time += $fifteen_mins;
}

print_r ($array_of_time);
```

Comment: is it possible with mysql?

Comment: both php/mysql. But mysql preferable

Comment: I can't think of a straight way of doing it via MySQL. The indirect way of doing it would be to create a table which contains all the 15-minute intervals in 24 hours, and then you can do `SELECT fifteen_mins FROM fifteen_mins_table WHERE fifteen_mins >= '2013-08-28 1:45:00' AND fifteen_mins <= '2013-08-28 22:15:00'`.

Comment: Otherwise, see something similar [posted here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510012/get-a-list-of-dates-between-two-dates) using temporary table and stored procedure.

Comment: Exactly you need to do it in PHP and store it in table

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom MySQL function and Procedures with the following signatures.

1. **CREATE FUNCTION ToUpper15**(dateParam DATETIME)
2. **CREATE FUNCTION ToLower15**(dateParam DATETIME)
3. **CREATE PROCEDURE AddIntervalMinutes**(startdate DATETIME, enddate DATETIME, interval INT)

Here is an example of some **pseudo** MySQL Code, I have never programmed MySQL, I tried to look for the documentation and its terrible, otherwise this is really a 30 minute Task, if you can find documentation of the Syntax of the Language.

Keep in mind

- When you round up above 45 minutes you are rounding to the next hour
- Do the same with ToLower15
- Use system function AddTime() to do the 15 minute interval

Below is how you might do this

```
CREATE FUNCTION ToUpper15(dateParam DATETIME) 
RETURNS DATETIME
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
   DECLARE dateYear   INT;
   DECLARE dateMonth  INT;
   DECLARE dateDay    INT;
   DECLARE dateHour   INT;
   DECLARE dateMinute INT;

   SET dateYear   = YEAR(dateParam);
   SET dateMonth  = MONTH(dateParam);
   SET dateDay    = DAY(dateParam);
   SET dateHour   = HOUR(dateParam);
   SET dateMinute = MINUTE(dateParam);

   IF (dateMinute >= 0 AND dateMinute < 15) THEN
      SET dateMinute = 15;
   ELSEIF (dateMinute >= 15  AND dateMinute < 30) THEN
      SET dateMinute = 30;
   ELSEIF (dateMinute >= 30  AND dateMinute < 45) THEN
      SET dateMinute = 45;
   ELSEIF (dateMinute >= 45  AND dateMinute < 60) THEN
      BEGIN
         SET dateMinute = 0;
         SET dateHour = dateHour + 1;
      END
   END IF;

   RETURN CONCAT(dateYear, '-', dateMonth, '-', dateDay, ' ', dateHour, ':', 'dateMinute');
END
```